# iptables block torrenting port on openvpn VPS

Tags: iptables, port

So I know you can't really block p2p without doing some layer solutions but my problem is much simpler. I am in a country that torrenting is fine (no one cares) but accessing basic sites like youtube or facebook or ... is heavily censored. For this reason I rent a VPS, run openvpn on it and use its connection myself and some close family members. The problem is that they might not intentionally 'slip' and have the torrenting app running while in vpn mode, which can result in locking the vps.

I am thinking I can set all qbittorrents to use a specific port always, like 8999 and block any connection to the vps that uses port 8999. Is that possible? How do I go on doing this? Is it effective?

VPS is running ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Do you really need to forward more than HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: I use udp on maybe 1194 for openvpn (I have to check), ssh and ftp which is 22, and squid proxy which is set to port 40446. I also use mtproto proxy on some port too. So I guess you mean block everything else, but doesn't it mean if qbittorent is running in openvpn it is essentially using port 1194 (openvpn) ?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: make sure you have an alternative way to get into your VPN before you start playing around with firewall rules. You can really easily lock yourself out. Something like a console provided by the VPN provider would be ideal. If you don't have this, set up an `at` job to automatically flush the iptables ruleset before you start playing with it.*

You can filter traffic going from the OpenVPN interface to the kernel:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 8999 -j REJECT
```

(replace `tun0` with the interface that OpenVPN creates)

This will reject port 8999 coming in over the VPN interface. Note that this change is not persistent. Refer to the documentation of the iptables-wrapper you use, if any, on how to make this change persistent.

The default on Ubuntu would be `ufw`, which would be:

```
ufw deny in on tun0 proto tcp to any port 8999
```

Resulting in:

```
mtak@E2QJZJW2:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8999/tcp on tun0           DENY        Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8999/tcp (v6) on tun0      DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

From a security standpoint, it's probably better to set up an iptables ruleset that blocks everything, *except* what you explicitly allow.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the "VPN for something, but not everything" problem is to use an HTTP proxy. This is suitable for tunneling only web browser traffic.

The setup is really easy:

- Make sure your VPN client does *not* change the default route (like `redirect-gateway` with OpenVPN or `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` with WireGuard)
- Have a proxy server (eg. Squid) running and listening on the VPN subnet
- Set only your web browser to use this proxy

All applications that do not know about the proxy will continue sending traffic directly to the internet.

Of course, there are some caveats: When the VPN is not connected, the browser will not work. Some browsers make it possible to quickly toggle proxies, either natively or with extensions. If you want to tunnel other traffic (like SSH), this solution won't work most of the time (though it could for all TCP connections).

---

Peer-to-peer applications like BitTorrent are usually capable of working around blocked ports. They can use reverse connections, random ports and whatnot. I wouldn't rely on something so brittle.